# SQL Setting Week Numbers For Months From Monday to Sunday

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to set the week number for months in a table. The logic is the first week starts on the first day of the month until the first Sunday and the rest of the weeks start on every Monday following that. I am having trouble implementing this though. Any Ideas? My code looks something like this.

I had previously received help here to set the week numbers for the entire years in a similar way. It looks like the following:

```
UPDATE [DimTime] 
SET [WeekNumberOfYear] = DATEPART(WEEK,[Date]) - CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[Date])     in (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: can you give some examples please ?

Comment: I assume 2013-12-01 sunday will make the cause the whole week to be week 1

Comment: Example for the current month 2013-04-01 to the Sunday would be week 1. Then the next 3 weeks would be 2, 3, 4. On 2012-04-28 the Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday would be week 5 and the Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday of the next month would be week 1 of May.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a correct result:

```
UPDATE [HMDBDataMartBOS].[dbo].[Dimension.DimTime] 
SET [NaturalWeekNumberOfYear] = datediff(d, datediff(d, 0, 
dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, [Date]), 0))/7*7 - 7,[Date])/7
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost exactly what I am looking for except that for example where the last week of the Month starting on Monday has 2 days the week number should set just for those two days and when the new month begins the week number should go back to 1. This sets the week number back to 1 for that last week even if it is still in the same month.

Comment: @Tartarus14 now I get it, here you are. Examples with input and expected output often helps understanding the problem. Sad that complex equations like this rarely give any upvotes

Comment: Yes this worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you. I need to improve on my SQL skills but help is always appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tartarus14 this complexity is not the best place to start

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
--Sample data
DECLARE @bob TABLE(dat DATE)
INSERT INTO @bob VALUES ('2012/04/01'), ('2012/04/06'), ('2012/04/07'), ('2012/04/08'),('2012/04/15'),('2012/04/30')

SET DATEFIRST 1 -- make Monday the first day of the week

--and the results
SELECT DATEPART(DAY,dat)/7 + 1 MonthWeek
FROM @bob
```